# How do I reverse Amazon S3 CDN links to WordPress Media files, so they point back to the server's copy. Using W3 Total Cache

Tags: wordpress, caching, amazon-s3, cdn, w3-total-cache

Done extensive googling on this. I setup a CDN to handle huge amount of traffic on a site launch. Now I need to pull the images back to the server, and update links/refs to the files to point back to the local server copy, instead of the CDN.

It's a standard WordPress install, using W3 Total Cache and a single S3 Bucket.

Any ideas?

Thanks, Tom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are comfortable working from the command line then this isn't terribly difficult. Use WP-CLI (http://wp-cli.org) to search and replace values in your database. You will most likely need to do a search/replace for each image you have listed in your database.

- If they aren't already there, make sure your copy all the
  images back down to your server and put them where you want them.
- Use wp-cli to just search your database and find all the
  references to your S3 bucket.
- Go one by one and replace the S3 url with one that points to
  your local server.

After you do your first one or two, load a page displaying that image, it should be loading locally.

wp-cli will search your entire database and even unpack serialized values to search them. it's a great tool for this kind of task. We use it a lot at getpantehon.com to manage different tasks.

Cheers!

=C=

Comment: Ah cheers Cal. Handling serialized values is handy! Don't need it for this project, but I know in the past it's been a pain.

Totally happy doing it that way, just wondered if there was a way of doing it with W3 Total Cache. Seems a bit odd if not. Thanks :)